# Producing a semi-RNG with a reproducible outcome in C (no random/urandom)

Tags: c, random, dataset, key, predictive

I wish to create a "randomness", or at least a large amount of entropy given certain data sets. The outcome must be predictable/constant, though, based on various factors, what datasets are used, etc. So I'm not looking to just read from random/urandom. I need this to be completely reproducible. I just want the spread to be varied enough across datasets using fairly limited key sizes. I suppose a rough idea:

[Key] --> [DatasetA] --> [Series of reproducible numbers]. Numbers that will significantly change based on a small modification to the key and any additional variable. Please note I'm trying to avoid just hashing as my requirement demands a lookup of datasets from the that will still simulate randomness without being random. It's procedurally-generated, but reproducible. I would prefer it be implementable in C as I want to use it for a (non-school) project. It's a hobby, but essentially I want to in the end be able to know certain criteria will produce very very varied results. Everything must be self-contained (no external dependence, just within the code and datasets, and keys).

If I'm looking at this from the wrong perspective, I'm open to other suggestions, but obviously it'd be preferable to not have to write the rest of the code-base from scratch.

I've already tried several "made-up" "algorithms" based on key size and contents and dataset contents. I'm not getting sufficient entropy, though.

[b]Update:[/b]
Thanks to Severrin's answer, I was able to get a baseline for my key. After some tweaking by using the found piece of data and they using it to seed the whole process over, it's working. My "rooms" are very nicely varied and I can still reproduce them. I supposed it took just out of the box thinking on my part as well.

Thanks everyone,

- Nate

Comment: I don't have many answers, but I would like to offer this [site](https://www.random.org/).  Not just a source of random data -- (which I know you don't want) -- it is an education/treatise in obtaining random data in uncommon ways.  It might give you valuable food for thought in creating a unique solution.

Comment: There are plenty of [pseudorandom number generators listed at Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators).

Comment: Your wording is not clear. It seems as if you want the generated numbers to be some function of a key and the dataset. Is that so? But you also say you are trying to avoid hashing. However, any function that generates a number in a fixed range from a key and a dataset is a hash function. You should clarify what you want and why you want to avoid hashing.

Comment: Re “I'm not getting sufficient entropy, though”: State how you determined this.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: What I meant was avoid built-in/traditional hash functions because saying md5sum X does not include dataset Y. AFAIK, hashing is using a set of math functions to a given piece of data. That's what I was taught is CS at least... I don't want to hash X across Y to generate XY, I want to generate Z from a function of X & Y similar to rogue-alike games did... If that makes more sense. Sorry if my wording isn't perfect, I grew up in a mixed English/Afrikaans family so I have no 1st/2nd language and took a year English course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is simple [Linear Congruential Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) for 64bit -> 64bit full period mapping, together with inverse function.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// parameters from https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.05304.pdf
uint64_t m = 0xd1342543de82ef95ULL;
uint64_t c = 0x1ULL;

uint64_t im = 6281218453581128637ULL; // modular inverse from m using Mathematica ModularInverse[m, 2^64]

uint64_t lcg(uint64_t xi) { // direct LCG
    return m*xi + c;
}

 uint64_t ilcg(uint64_t xp) { // inverse LCG, such that ilcq(lcg(q)) == q
    return (xp - c)*im;
}

int main() {
    
    uint64_t idx = 987610342345234534ULL;
    
    printf( "LCG is %llu\n", lcg(idx) );
    printf( "INV is %llu\n", ilcg(lcg(135797531ULL)) );

    return 0;
}
```

And here is 128bit LCG

```
typedef union {
    uint8_t     c[16];
    __uint128_t ui;
} x128;

const x128 zm = { .c = {0xdb,0x36,0x35,0x77,0x34,0xe3,0x4a,0xbb,0x00,0x50,0xd0,0x76,0x1f,0xcd,0xfc,0x15} }; // parameters from https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.05304.pdf
const x128 zc = { .c = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01} };

__uint128_t lcg(__uint128_t xi) {
    return zm.ui*xi + zc.ui;
}

void prn128(__uint128_t x) {
    printf("0x");
    for (int i = 0; i != 16; ++i) {
        printf("%02x", (int)((x >> 8*i)) & 0xff);
    }
    printf("\n");    
}

int main() {
    __uint128_t a = (__uint128_t)9129178291273918391ULL * 19284633241ULL * 3173197ULL;
    
    prn128(zm.ui);
    prn128(zc.ui);
    prn128(a);
    prn128(lcg(a));    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, not exactly what I'm looking for but it's a starting point. The problem is there's still a lots that's similar if changing only zc. But it IS a good start point. I think I need to dust off my High School Math text books, too, haha. I'll mark this right if nobody posts anything closer to my needs.